# Let $f(x) = p(x)/q(x)$ and $deg(p) = deg(q) - 1$. Show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = 0$ where $f(x) = \dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ and $deg(p) = deg(q) - 1$.  Also, $q(x)$ has no real roots.  I was considering integrating along the contour $C_R$, where $C_R$ is the real line segment from $-R$ to $R$ and the upper semi circle, in which case

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_R} f(z)dz  = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R f(x) dx+\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)dz  = 2\pi i\sum_{k}Res(f, z_k)$$

where $z_k$ are the zeroes of $q(x)$ in the upper half plane, and $\Gamma_R$ is the upper semicircle.  However, I'm not sure where to proceed from here

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $deg(p)=deg(q)-1$, your function is not integrable at $\infty$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $q$ has no zeros?

Comment: I'm assuming $q$ has no real roots, but it may have complex zeroes.

Comment: Then this is integrable if and only if $\deg q\geq \deg p+2$. So what is your definition of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ in this case?

Comment: The function decays too slowly, for large $x$ it behaves like $\frac{c}{x}$.

Comment: @julien Why doesn't this integral converge?

Comment: Well,for instance take $f(x)=2x/(1+x^2)$. Then $\int_{0}^Bf(x)dx=\ln(1+B^2)\longrightarrow +\infty$ as $B\longrightarrow +\infty$. What you are talking about here, I guess, is [Cauchy Pincipal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which is not the Lebesgue integral over $(-\infty,+\infty)$. That's $\lim_{B\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{-B}^Bf(x)dx$.

Answer (score 4):

It's not true in general.  For example, the Cauchy principal value integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x-i} = \pi i$$

EDIT: More generally, the Cauchy principal value

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x-r} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x-{\text Im}(r)} = \cases{\pi i & if $\text{Im}(r)>0$\cr
                 -\pi i & if $\text{Im}(r)<0$}$$

The Cauchy principal value of 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dz$ is $\pi i$ times the difference between the sum
of the residues of $f$ in the upper half plane and the sum of the residues in the lower half plane.

Answer (score 3):

The result is not true, and it is hard to see how to "save" it. If $p(x)=x+a$ and $q(x)=x^2+1$, then $\lim\limits_{R\to+\infty}\int\limits_{-R}^{+R}f(x)\mathrm dx=a\pi$ hence the Cauchy principal value exists but is not zero in general.

Comment: To save it, we would need for instance to assume that $p/q$ is odd. Which makes it a highly noninteresting fact wich has nothing to do with rational functions...

Comment: @julien Indeed.